# How to add a font awesome icon into a haml form submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, font-awesome, haml

I'm currently trying to add a search `font-awesome icon` into my forms submit button, here's what I've done so far:

```
 = simple_form_for :search, url: search_products_path, method: :post, html: { class: "mx-auto"}  do |f|
    = f.input :code
    = f.submit 'Search', :class => "btn btn-success" do
      %i.fa.fa-search
```

Currently no `font-awesome icon` appears, if I use:

```
%i.fa.fa-search
= f.submit 'Search', :class => "btn btn-success"
```

Then the icon does appear, on the same line but obviously not inside the submit button. Currently I've not found a solution to do this with `haml`.

Comment: f.submit raw("<i class='fa fa-search'</i>")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot combine passing block and text argument to f.submit.

So you should do:

```
= f.submit raw("<i class='fa fa-search'</i> Search"), :class => "btn btn-success"
```

or preferably:

```
= f.submit :class => "btn btn-success" do
  %i.fa.fa-search Search
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Search` from submit and add it inside the block.